# Explanation of vim :%w !pbcopy command

Tags: macos, vim

I know `:w` means to save the file, but what does `:%w` do?

And also what does `!pbcopy` do?

Answer (score 3):

See `:h :w_c`. It sends some lines as standard input to an external command (accessible via your shell). The `%` sign is a range, it tells vim to send the whole file, not only a part.

Note that `:w! somefile.txt` is totally different from `:w !ext_command` (with a space after `:w`).

I don't know about the `pbcopy` external command, but you certainly can do something like `$ pbcopy -h` in your shell to get some help about it.

Comment: It turns out `pbcopy` is a mac osx command that writes standard input to system clipboard. In my shell on ubuntu it is aliased to `xclip -selection clipboard -in`.